# Plot not filling the slide in R presentation

Tags: r, rstudio

If I make a default R presentation in Rstudio, everything looks okay, but the plot doesn't fill the whole slide.

[image]

This is the same whether in full screen or in the browser.

The [documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations) says "When the only content on a slide is an image, then the image will fill all available space on the slide". And it mentions that same goes for plots.

What am I missing here? What do I need to do to have the plot fill the whole slide?

I updated my RStudio to Version 0.99.903

Answer (score 3):

Use `out.width="100%"` in your chunk options

`{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="100%"}`

Comment: Wow, how did you find this! :) Thank you! However, It seems to just stretch the plot. Is it possible to have it re-size the plot?